# Multiply number by 10 n times

Tags: math, dart

Is there a better mathematical way to multiply a number by 10 n times in Dart than the following (below). I don't want to use the math library, because it would be overkill. It's no big deal; however if there's a better (more elegant) way than the "for loop", preferably one line, I'd like to know.

```dart
int iDecimals = 3;
int iValue    = 1;

print ("${iValue} to power of ${iDecimals} = ");
for (int iLp1 = 1; iLp1 <= iDecimals; iLp1++) {
  iValue *= 10;
}

print ("${iValue}");
```

Comment: But you are not rising a number to a power? You are multiplying it by a ten to power, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the criteria was that the answer needed to not require the math library and needed to be fast and ideally a mathematical-solution (not String), and because using the exponential solution requires too much overhead - String, double, integer, I think that the only answer that meets the criteria is as follows :

```
for (int iLp1=0; iLp1<iDecimal; iLp1++, iScale*=10);
```

It is quite fast, doesn't require the "math" library, and is a one-liner

Answer (score 2):

You are not *raising to a power* of ten, you are *multiplying by* a power of ten. That is in your code the answer will be `iValue * 10^(iDecimals)` while raising to a power means `iValue^10`.

Now, your code still contains exponentiation and what it does is raises ten to the power `iDecimals` and then multiplies by `iValue`. Raising may be made way more efficient. (*Disclaimer: I've never written a line of dart code before and I don't have an interpreter to test, so this might not work right away*.)

```
int iValue = 1;
int p = 3;
int a = 10;

// The following code raises `a` to the power of `p`
int tmp = 1;
while (p > 1) {
  if (p % 2 == 0) {
    p /= 2;
  } else {
    c *= a;
    p = (p - 1) / 2;
  }
  a *= a;
}
a *= t;
// in our example now `a` is 10^3

iValue *= a;

print ("${iValue}");
```

This exponentiation algorithm is very straightforward and it is known as [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Answer (score 1):

Use the math library.  Your idea of doing so being "overkill" is misguided.  The following is easier to write, easier to read, fewer lines of code, and most likely faster than anything you might replace it with:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int iDecimals = 3;
  int iValue    = 1;

  print("${iValue} times ten to the power of ${iDecimals} = ");
  iValue *= pow(10, iDecimals);
  print(iValue);
}
```

Perhaps you're deploying to JavaScript, concerned about deployment size, and unaware that `dart2js` does tree shaking?

Finally, if you *do* want to raise a number to the power of ten, as you asked for but didn't do, simply use `pow(iValue, 10)`.

Comment: Sorry about my terminology. What I want to do is as per my example, and which the following appears to also achieve "iValue = pow(10, iDecimals);". I did want to achieve it with using "math", but the speed difference may change that. It is to "scale" a decimal to an integer. Eg. "12.34 * 100;". The number of decimals is passed.

Comment: @BrianOh Yes, I figured that's probably what you meant; it just seemed my answer would be incomplete without also addressing what you asked for.  Again, I highly recommend getting over your reservations and just using the math library.  It's perfectly appropriate to use a library in Dart for just one function; the tree shaking will ensure that you're not pulling in more than you need.

Comment: FWIW, using the exponent "1e2" (in this case), is too slow (12 * pow time) because of the String, the double and the casting to integer. The "for loop" is quite fast (2* pow time). However, I am modifying a generic currency class that I wrote some time back, and would prefer to not rely on external libraries at all. The following achieves it in 1 line "for (int iLp1=0; iLp1<iDecimal; iLp1++, iScale*=10);" As I said, it's no big deal, it has some appeal (to me) to be a minimalist, and a one-liner that's fast with no external dependencies achieves that - for whatever reason.

Comment: @BrianOh It's hard for me to see the core libraries as "external dependencies", and I find that one-liner to be the true overkill -- adding complexity for no reason -- but to each their own.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right - but it's hard to change old KISS habits.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you don't want to use any math library, i think this is the best way to compute the power of a number. The time complexity of this code snippet also seems minimal. If you need a one line solution you will have to use some math library function.

Btw, you are not raising to the power but simply multiplying a number with 10 n times.

Comment: @kirelagin Do you have any better solution ?

Comment: He said he want to raise to the power of '10' and that is what he is doing.

Comment: Regarding the complexity, This loop is linear time, i.e., O(n).

Comment: Yeah, I misread the code. Anyway, linear time is, of course, not the best you can get.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But he don't want to use a math library so this seems fine. :)

Comment: No, wait, I didn't misread it. He's multiplying the number by ten-to-the-power. Not rising.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to multiply something by a power of 10? If so, I believe Dart supports scientific notation. So the above value would be written as: `iValue = 1e3;`

Which is equal to 1000. If you want to raise the number itself to the power of ten, I think your only other option is to use the Math library.

Comment: Thanks, I did come across that after posting question. It is not strictly mathematical (string), eg:  int iScale2 = (double.parse("1e${iDecimals}")).toInt(); However, I'll "tick" your answer if nothing else is "better".

Comment: Unfortunately, because the decimal value is a variable, it is necessary to use String interpolation, plus double assignment, plus integer casting. The end-result is much slower than the alternative.